# How can I change logger pattern?

Tags: java, scala, logging, log4j

Does any one know how to change the log pattern in log console in the Scala code? I want to change the pattern to "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n".

I have the below code but it does not work

```
val rootLogger: Logger = Logger.getRootLogger
val pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"
rootLogger.removeAllAppenders()
rootLogger.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(new PatternLayout(pattern)))
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? Your pattern doesn't have the `%d{...}`, is this a typo?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, my pattern is "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n". "it does not work" means when I execute my code, the log pattern does not change to this pattern I specified.

Comment: Can you specify the version of Log4j? Are you using `log4j:log4j:1.2.17` or some replacement (`reload4j`, `log4j-over-slf4j`, `log4j-1.2-api`)?

Comment: When do you execute this code? What output do you see? We'll need more details to help.